# Extracting numbers from a text file using perl

Tags: regex, perl, text

I have a text file which has data of the form ..

> > *****yz = 1.4333******
> >
> > result= 3.58e-01
> >
> > ---
> >
> > *******ayf = 25.00
> >     ****yz = 1.34
> >     result= 3.24e-01

---

I want to extract the values beside result & push it into an array.

Comment: Do you want this `3.58e-01` as a value because if you edit `if($_=~/ result= (\d+.\d+e-\d+)/){` to `if($_=~/result= (\d+.\d+e-\d+)/){`, This will capture the above described output only.
Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: @AbhiNickz: I've added further details.

Comment: Try giving your file name as "output_vth_".$vth.".txt"

Comment: @Jaison: it gives a syntax error when i change the file name to that.

Comment: @rahdirs What is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there more code you didn't give in the example? Like output of the result array? Otherwise there are some things to consider:

- leading space in regex: This will not match your example, since `result` there starts at the beginning of the line. In general, if you want to be more flexible with possibly occuring spaces, insert `\s*` at the according places.
- scientific number matching: If you expect numbers other than scientific notation with negative exponents to appear, you have to adopt your regex that way. There are plenty of example out there.

For your extended code:

- please use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in every script
- use the 3-argument-mode of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and possibly lexical file handlers (`my $fh` instead of `FH`). The 3-argument-mode ensures you don't forget to specify the actual mode (read/write/etc.) in which to open the file, amongst other things.
- `close(FH)` your file handlers before using them on other files

Not closing `IN2` seems to be one problem in your code, for instance.

Comment: Please use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in all your scripts - this really helps alot. Then try to use open in the 3-argument-mode - that way you don't forget to specify if you open it for reading or writing. And `close` all the file handles you don't need anymore, especially if you use them again. I don't see any closing of the `IN2` handle before you try to open it again. And you open it without specifying whether for input or output...

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die;
my @array;
/result\s*=\s*(\S+)/i and push @array, 0+$1 while <$fh>;    # 0+$1 or just $1
close $fh;
```